# Invalid CRL distribution points in certs after CA migration

Tags: active-directory, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services, pki

I have recently migrated an Enterprise CA from a Windows Server 2003 box to a Windows Server 2012 R2 box using the [Active Directory Certificate Services Migration Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn486797(v=ws.11).aspx).

The CA was running entirely on the one machine, and looks as though it was a typical "next, next, finish" install done without any thought or planning because they realised they needed a CA at some point.

The guide recommends that you name the destination server the same as the source server if possible. However, it include additional steps that should be carried out if the source and destination have different names. I completed these additional steps during the migration.

However, I am left with an issue which the guide doesn't seem to address. When the CA was originally deployed, the CPD and AIA URLs were left as the out-of-box defaults. This means the CDP and AIA URLs in already issued certificates reference the old machine by name, e.g:

http://server01.ad.contoso.com/CertEnroll/crl.crl

I'm no expert with AD CS, but I gather best practice is to break that dependency by using something like:

http://crl.contoso.com/CertEnroll/crl.crl

... but it's too late now the certificates have been issued.

I'm guessing the Migration Guide on TechNet assumes you've followed best practice when deploying your CA, meaning you wouldn't hit this issue.

So, my question is, what's the best way to address the issue? I've seen a couple of people suggesting I should create a CNAME pointing the old CA server name to the new CA server. Others have said I can select each of the Certificate Templates within MMC and ask it to re-issue the certificates associated with them. I'm unsure whether either of these is really the best approach.

Comment: Reissuing the certificates from the console will only work if all your certificates are issued to domain joined clients - that is, clients that enrolled using the WCCE protocol.  Certificates that were manually issued (such as to a Linux box) wouldn't automatically update this way.  The easiest way is to change the URL to the new one and use a CNAME until all the old certificates have expired/renewed. You can then remove that CNAME.

Comment: @garethTheRed In this particular situation, I think they may all be issued to domain joined clients. I'll double check